# Check my math: Calculating the size of extension cord needed

Tags: power, resistance, mains, math

I think I've done this right, but I don't trust myself. Will you check my math and see if I'm right about this, or correct my error if I'm wrong?

#### The facts

- I have a device (A Yamaha Stagepas 400i sound system) that consumes 70w at 1/8 power (100v-240v 50hz/60hz)
- The device needs to be used 200 feet from the nearest outlet, an outdoor GFCI 120v outlet.

#### Assumptions

- At full power the device consumes ~800w
- The outlet is delivering at least 10a

#### Math

- 800w at 120v = 6.67 amps
- A 16ga copper extension cord carrying 3.4a for 200 feet will lose 10.5 volts (from http://yeroc.us/calculators/wire-resistance)
- 120-10.5 = 109.5v
- To get 800w at 109.5v, we need 7.4a

#### Conclusion

- Since the device will run at a minimum of 100v, and the outlet will deliver up to 10a, using 200ft of 16ga copper extension cord should be acceptable in this scenario (and a higher gauge will also work well).

Comment: *sigh* No, I just need to check my eyes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work it backwards, then the amplifier can be dissipating 800 watts with only 100 volts available at its end of the long cable.

That's 8 amperes the amplifier will need, and if there's 120 volts at the socket and 100 volts at the amplifier's end of the cable, the maximum allowable cable resistance will be

R = (120V - 100V)/8 ohms = 2.5 ohms.

Since the cable will be 200 feet long, that'll be 2-1/2 ohms for the 400 foot round trip, which is 6.25 ohms per 1000 feet.

16 AWG has a resistance of 4.016 ohms per 1000 feet, so it would work.

But, since the cable itself will be dissipating about 20V * 8A = 160 watts, it'll heat up a little, increasing its resistance, and if it's lying in the sun it'll get even hotter, increasing its resistance even more.

So, just for insurance I'd bump the cable up to 14 AWG or even monster 12 AWG if there was a chance I'd need it later, and I'd do the math just for fun.  Just not now... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Good in theory, but... the amplifier won't draw extra current just because it's experiencing a voltage brownout. Said otherwise, its output power is likely to fall off if it's not getting fully 120VAC.

If you absolutely REQUIRE (unlikely) that it deliver 800W of output power, then you'll have to install an autotransformer at the source outlet and use it to adjust the voltage AT THAT OUTLET upwards 10.5V to 130.5VAC. Then the extension cord's drop will being that voltage right back to 120V where you want it to be.

At that distance, though... I believe I'd run no less than #12 extension cords and disregard voltage drop altogether. 200' is a long long run. #12 extension cords aren't much more expensive than #16 extension cords, and will later work for anything you can plug into them - a #16 extension cord is pretty limited for later uses.

Comment: "Good in theory, but... the amplifier won't draw extra current just because it's experiencing a voltage brownout"  Not necessarily true - this depends entirely on the nature of its power supply.  A switching regulator would at least *attempt* to draw more up to any inherent limits.

Comment: Agreed 100% on the 12ga cord. That was my thinking: Make sure the math works at 16ga, then buy heavier anyway, just for added margin.

Comment: Chris, when was the last time you saw an 800W audio amplifier with a switching regulator? Switching regulators have a strong tendency to be noisy in the auditory range.

Comment: Almost everything Crown and QSC (big time market share) ship these days has a SMPS, and the amplifier stage is swtiching as well. I heard of a topology where the supply rails tracked the input signal to gain extra efficiency. So the better question is probabl,y "When was the last time you saw an 800W audio amplifier without a switching regulator?"

Comment: TD: The power input spec's on the thing are 100 to 240 VRMS, 50/60Hz, it puts out about 400 watts, CW,  and the whole thing  weighs about 40 pounds.  Linear supply????

Comment: Let's back up a long way here. This is a Yamaha Stagepas 400i? I've just glanced at the spec sheet from Yamaha, and... that's no 800W amplifier. Speaker output 200W absolute peak at 4 ohms. Per channel. Two channels, correct? If that'd been 400WRMS per channel into 4 ohms, it'd have required a 100VDC supply BEFORE any switcher and AFTER any ripple had been removed, which is impossible at 100VAC. At 200W peak, it sounds considerably more realistic; that'd require only a 50VDC ripple-free supply before a switcher, and THAT could be achieved.

Comment: I still doubt the presence of a switching power supply in it, though. Until proven otherwise, I'd be inclined to believe it has a heavily filtered linear or unregulated supply for everything but the DSP features. I know of one really really good way to tell...